# Why is the following line producing a 1-dimensional array instead of a 2-dimensional one?

Tags: arrays, csv, matrix, julia

I'm attempting to read a CSV file in `Julia 1.1`, producing a matrix of strings with the same layout as the original data in the csv file. In other words, if my CSV-file was

```
a,s,d,f,g,h
q,w,e,r,t,y
```

my matrix should look like

```
a s d f g h
q w e r t y
```

I don't know how many lines there are in the file, so I attempted the following:

```
csv_file_lines = readlines("./" * filename)
data = hcat( map( x -> split(x, ","), csv_file_lines ) )
```

In one of my shorter example files, the output is

```
Array{SubString{String},1}[["date", "watch_time_minutes", "views", "average_view_duration", "video_thumbnail_impressions", "video_thumbnail_impressions_ctr"]; ["2019-03-04", "83.2051", "28", "2.9716", "318", "6.2893"]; ["2019-03-05", "43.6223", "12", "3.6352", "79", "10.1266"]; ["2019-03-06", "5.5267", "2", "2.7633", "33", "6.0606"]; ["2019-03-07", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0"]; ["2019-03-08", "58.7133", "11", "5.3376", "86", "8.1395"]; ["2019-03-09", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0"]; ["2019-03-10", "20.205", "4", "5.0512", "14", "7.1429"]; ["2019-03-11", "10.7013", "4", "2.6753", "24", "4.1667"]; ["2019-03-12", "1.3", "1", "1.3", "5", "20"]; ["2019-03-13", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0"]; ["2019-03-14", "14.7383", "6", "2.4564", "65", "9.2308"]; ["2019-03-15", "20.75", "7", "2.9643", "25", "12"]; ["2019-03-16", "31.0083", "4", "7.7521", "0", ""]; ["2019-03-17", "6.8624", "2", "3.4312", "0", ""]; ["2019-03-18", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0"]; ["2019-03-19", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0"]; ["2019-03-20", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0"]; ["2019-03-21", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0"]]
```

which is a one-dimensional array of `Substring` arrays, instead of a 2-dimensional array of `String`s (or `Substring`s in this case). What am I doing wrong here? Changing `hcat` to `vcat` does nothing to alleviate this issue.

#### Edit

I would prefer to do this without the `CSV` package or dataframes, to reduce overhead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think `readdlm` from the standard library DelimitedFiles is what you're looking for:

```
julia> using DelimitedFiles

julia> readdlm("file.csv", ',', String)
2×6 Array{String,2}:
 "a"  "s"  "d"  "f"  "g"  "h"
 "q"  "w"  "e"  "r"  "t"  "y"
```

This produces a `2x6` matrix of strings.

Check `?readdlm` for details.